# Im Using an If Else Statement How can I show my picture based off of what the user inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am Trying to display my image using an if else statement. the text is working but the image isn't.

HTML

```
  <button type="button" id="textAnswer">Show Text Answer</button>
    <p id="yes"></p>
    <button type="button" id="graphicAnswer">Show Graphic Answer</button>
    <p id="no"></p>
    <img
      id="enoughGas"
      src="IMG/enoughGas.jpg"
      alt="There is enough Gas for you to make it across the desert."
    />
    <img
      id="notEnoughGas"
      src="IMG/notEnoughGas.jpg"
      alt="There is not enough Gas for you to make it across the desert."
    />
```

CSS

```
img {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
//Prompt the user for the amount of gas in their tank
let gallons = prompt("How many gallons of gas can your car hold?");
let percent = prompt("What percentage of gas is left in your tank? Only Whole Numbers (1-100) don't include the % sign.");
let mpg = prompt("How many miles per gallon does your car get?");

//Calculate the number of miles the car can travel with current gas in the tank.
let miles = (gallons * percent) / 100 * mpg;

//Display results
if (miles >= 200) {
document.querySelector("#textAnswer").addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
document.querySelector("#yes").innerHTML = "Yes, you can make it without stopping for gas!";
}) 
document.querySelector("#GraphicAnswer").addEventListener("click", function (e)
{
    document.querySelector("#notEnoughGas")
    img.src = "IMG/enoughGas.jpg";
    document.querySelector("#enoughGas").style.display="block";
})
} else  {
    document.querySelector("#textAnswer").addEventListener("click", function(e)
    {
    document.querySelector("#no").innerHTML = "No, you can't make it without stopping for gas!";
    }) 
    document.querySelector("#GraphicAnswer").addEventListener("click", function (e)
    {
        document.querySelector("#notEnoughGas")
        img.src = "IMG/notEnoughGas.jpg";
        document.querySelector("#notEnoughGas").style.display="block";
    })
}
```

I have tried adding the image via JS. Adding the image Via HTML within the button. And can't seem to figure out which is the right formula for it. If you could help me that would be great.

Comment: `img` isn’t defined anywhere and `document.querySelector("#notEnoughGas")` by itself does not do anything. Adding event listeners inside an `if`–`else` statement is not likely to be the correct approach. You’re never _hiding_ the other image; use `.style.display = "none";`. Consider using the [`hidden` attribute](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) with [`toggleAttribute`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element IDs are case sensitive. Your bug is that in your HTML, you use the id `graphicAnswer`, but in your Javascript you are looking for an element with the id `GraphicAnswer`. Just make them match, and it will work.

```js
//Prompt the user for the amount of gas in their tank
let gallons = prompt("How many gallons of gas can your car hold?");
let percent = prompt("What percentage of gas is left in your tank? Only Whole Numbers (1-100) don't include the % sign.");
let mpg = prompt("How many miles per gallon does your car get?");

//Calculate the number of miles the car can travel with current gas in the tank.
let miles = (gallons * percent) / 100 * mpg;

//Display results
if (miles >= 200) {
  document.querySelector("#textAnswer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.querySelector("#yes").innerHTML = "Yes, you can make it without stopping for gas!";
  }) 
  document.querySelector("#graphicAnswer").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    document.querySelector("#enoughGas").style.display="block";
  })
}
else {
  document.querySelector("#textAnswer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.querySelector("#no").innerHTML = "No, you can't make it without stopping for gas!";
  }) 
  document.querySelector("#graphicAnswer").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    document.querySelector("#notEnoughGas").style.display="block";
  })
}
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="textAnswer">Show Text Answer</button>
<p id="yes"></p>
<button type="button" id="graphicAnswer">Show Graphic Answer</button>
<p id="no"></p>
<img id="enoughGas" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Flat_tick_icon.svg/240px-Flat_tick_icon.svg.png" alt="There is enough Gas for you to make it across the desert."/>
<img id="notEnoughGas" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Flat_cross_icon.svg/240px-Flat_cross_icon.svg.png" alt="There is not enough Gas for you to make it across the desert."/>
```